# cross compiling kernel for raspberry pi 4

Tags: linux-kernel, cross-compiling, boot, sd-card, raspberry-pi4

I am new to linux and I really need your help

I am working on project for my end of studies internship : controlling sensors and displaying the result on an LCD screen

for that I will use raspberry and create a QT application for displaying the result of the sensors.

The boot time need to be very minimal so for that I want to create a minimal kernel for my raspberri pi-4 b

I did the cross compilation for arm64:

```
mkdir rasp_arm64
cd rasp_arm64/
git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux
sudo apt-get install qemu-system-arm
sudo apt-get install lzop
sudo apt-get install gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu
cd linux/
make -j8 ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu- mrproper
make -j8 ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu- bcm2711_defconfig
make -j8 ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu- Image modules dtbs
```

this is what I did

How can I actually make a .img file for my a bootalbe SDcard for my raspberry pi 4?

I also worked on https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/kernel/building.md

and I added (cen someone also clarify why we need this)
`KERNEL=kernel8`

and after that I did
`make ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu- Image modules dtbs`
`mkdir mnt`
`mkdir mnt/fat32`
`mkdir mnt/ext4`
`sudo mount /dev/sdb6 mnt/fat32`
`sudo mount /dev/sdb7 mnt/ext4`

```
 sudo env PATH=$PATH make ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu- INSTALL_MOD_PATH=mnt/ext4 modules_install

sudo cp mnt/fat32/$KERNEL.img mnt/fat32/$KERNEL-backup.img
```

I got an error telling that mnt/fat32/.img no such file or directory

I tried also

```
$ sudo cp arch/arm64/boot/dts/overlays/*.dtb* mnt/fat32/overlays/
cp: target 'mnt/fat32/overlays/' is not a directory
```

so I tried to create it

```
$ mkdir mnt/fat32/overlays
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘mnt/fat32/overlays’: Permission denied
```

can anyone please help me I am stuck in this error for 2 weeks now and I need to build my kernel to start working on it!

I don't know also if this version of kernel and this configuration are minimal. can I have a minimal boot time with this configuration (I think of changing the boot sequence and just enable the devices needed for my application at first but of course i don't know how to do it) If anyone can help please en-light me !! even if you just know a good tutoriel to recommand me or something..

I will be grateful if someone could help

Answer (score 0):

The obvious problem here is that `$KERNEL` is evaluating to nothing. This might be because it was assigned a value locally and was not exported.
Instead of `KERNEL=kernel8`, use

```sh
export KERNEL=kernel8
```

That would ensure that `$KERNEL` evaluated to `kernel8` wherever it is used, which would fix the problem and `sudo cp mnt/fat32/$KERNEL.img mnt/fat32/$KERNEL-backup.img` will be executed as `sudo cp mnt/fat32/kernel8.img mnt/fat32/kernel8-backup.img`.

Comment: Thank  you but it didn't work for me :( I just created a new directory and followed https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/kernel/building.md and replaced as you said            "KERNEL=kernel8"  by            'export KERNEL=kernel8' and i executed            'sudo cp mnt/fat32/kernel8.img mnt/fat32/kernel8-backup.img' but I got           'cp: cannot stat 'mnt/fat32/kernel8.img': No such file or directory' the same error

Comment: @amina I see. :( As much as I know, the command that is failing is the one that backups the current kernel image. If it doesn't exist, then there is no point in making a backup. Can you try continuing the procedure while skipping the backup i. e. `sudo cp ...` part?

Comment: i tried `$ sudo cp arch/arm64/boot/Image mnt/fat32/$KERNEL.img`  `$ sudo cp arch/arm64/boot/dts/broadcom/*.dtb mnt/fat32/`  I was okey but when I tried `$ sudo cp arch/arm64/boot/dts/overlays/*.dtb* mnt/fat32/overlays/` `cp: target 'mnt2/fat32/overlays/' is not a directory` `$ sudo cp arch/arm64/boot/dts/overlays/README mnt/fat32/overlays/`  `cp: cannot create regular file 'mnt2/fat32/overlays/': Not a directory`  so I tried to create overlays in mnt/fat32 but couldn't work `linux/mnt/fat32$ mkdir overlays mkdir: cannot create directory ‘overlays’: Permission denied` how can I fix this

Comment: the result of ls : `linux/mnt/fat32$ ls` is  `bcm2710-rpi-2-b.dtb bcm2711-rpi-400.dtb bcm2837-rpi-3-b.dtb bcm2710-rpi-3-b.dtb bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb bcm2837-rpi-3-b-plus.dtb bcm2710-rpi-3-b-plus.dtb bcm2711-rpi-cm4.dtb bcm2837-rpi-cm3-io3.dtb bcm2710-rpi-cm3.dtb bcm2837-rpi-3-a-plus.dtb kernel8.img`

Comment: Apparently, `kernel8.img` appears to be present in the results of `ls`! Does it still say that `kernel8.img` is not found?

Comment: yes `kernel8.img` appears int the `mnt/fat32` but when I tried to do `sudo cp mnt/fat32/kernel8.img mnt/fat32/kernel8-backup.img` after creating the kenel8.img it shows me the same error

Comment: @amina Are you sure it is `mnt/fat32` and not `/mnt/fat32`?

Comment: yes I am sure, sorry for my late replay ! I started using raspberry pi os lite for my application because I couldn't fix this errors

Answer (score 0):

```
mkdir rasp_off_exp
 cd rasp_off_exp/
 sudo apt install git bc bison flex libssl-dev make libc6-dev libncurses5-dev
 sudo apt install crossbuild-essential-arm64
 git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux
 cd linux/
 export KERNEL=kernel8
 make ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu- bcm2711_defconfig
 make -j8 ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu- Image modules dtbs
 lsblk
 mkdir mnt
 mkdir mnt/fat32
 mkdir mnt/ext4
 sudo mount /dev/mmcblk0p1 mnt/fat32
 sudo mount /dev/mmcblk0p2 mnt/ext4
 sudo env PATH=$PATH make ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu- INSTALL_MOD_PATH=mnt/ext4 modules_install
 sudo cp mnt/fat32/kernel8.img mnt/fat32/kernel8-backup.img
```

This is the code but
I got

```
cp: cannot stat 'mnt/fat32/kernel8.img': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

The instructions at https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/kernel/building.md are missing one step and switch the order of two other steps.
This works:

```
sudo cp arch/arm/boot/zImage mnt/fat32/$KERNEL.img 
sudo cp mnt/fat32/$KERNEL.img mnt/fat32/$KERNEL-backup.img  

sudo cp arch/arm/boot/dts/*.dtb mnt/fat32/  

sudo mkdir mnt/fat32/overlays 
sudo cp arch/arm/boot/dts/overlays/*.dtb* mnt/fat32/overlays/
```

Comment: I already tried to switch the order of the two first lines but didn't work for me. `sudo cp arch/arm64/boot/Image mnt3/fat32/$KERNEL.img`
`sudo cp mnt/fat32/$KERNEL.img mnt3/fat32/$KERNEL-backup.img`
`cp: cannot stat 'mnt/fat32/kernel8.img': No such file or directory` and after that I gave up and started using raspberry pi os lite . Thank you for helping